# Deferred initialization and mutable static borrowing [Rust]

Tags: multithreading, rust, lazy-static

My question is the following:

---

**Would it be possible to make a deferred initialization of an object and then borrow it as mutable for a `'static` lifetime?**

---

### Some context

First of all, I am going to show an example of what I mean by deferred initialization. The deferred initialization model that I have come up with is to use the crate `lazy_static` with a standard library `Mutex` holding an `Option<T>`. Here there is an example of a deferred initialization.

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub struct DeferredStruct {
    internal_field: u32,
}

impl DeferredStruct {
    pub fn new(internal_field: u32) -> Self {
        Self {
            internal_field,
        }
    }

    pub fn regular_function(&mut self) {
        self.internal_field += 1;
        println!("{}", self.internal_field);
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref MY_DEFERRED: Mutex<Option<DeferredStruct>> = Mutex::new(None);
}

fn main() {
    // Initial processing
    // ...
    // ...
    
    // The value 10 would be obtained from a configuration file on runtime.
    let deferred_struct = DeferredStruct::new(10);
    let mut lock = MY_DEFERRED.lock().unwrap();  
    lock.replace(deferred_struct);
    std::mem::drop(lock); // In this example we drop the lock to avoid a deadlock when calling another_function.
    // More processing
    // ...
    // ...
    let thread_handle = another_function();
    thread_handle.join().unwrap();
}

// From another part of the program and possibly from another thread we
// lock MY_DEFERRED and call regular_funcion on it.
fn another_function() -> JoinHandle<()> {
    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut lock = MY_DEFERRED.lock().unwrap();
        if let Some(deferred) = lock.as_mut() {
            deferred.regular_function();
        } 
    })
}
```

You can execute the above code in [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ed07f7aef1ef91509851d88e4f47df1) and check that it prints `11` correctly.

### Introducing a struct function that requires a static lifetime

Now, let's say I add a function inside `DeferredStruct` that will create a worker thread in order to execute some computations that will take a long time:

```
pub struct DeferredStruct {
    internal_field: u32,
}

impl DeferredStruct {
    pub fn new(internal_field: u32) -> Self {
        Self {
            internal_field,
        }
    }

    pub fn regular_function(&mut self) {
        self.internal_field += 1;
        println!("{}", self.internal_field);
    }

    pub fn static_function(&'static mut self) {
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            // Do something really long.
            // Finally I make some changes on self
            self.internal_field += 100;
        });
    }
}
```

In this case is required for `&mut self` to have a `'static` lifetime:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement.
```

Due to this, the function will take a `&'static mut self`.

The problem comes when trying to borrow the `DeferredStruct` inside the `Option` in `MY_DEFERRED` as `'static` and `mut`.

If I cannot borrow for `'static` and `mut` then I cannot call `deferred.static_function()`. As the value will not live for long enough.

```
error[E0597]: `lock` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:57:33
   |
57 |         if let Some(deferred) = lock.as_mut() {
   |                                 ^^^^---------
   |                                 |
   |                                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                 argument requires that `lock` is borrowed for `'static`
...
60 |     })
   |     - `lock` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Here there is a minimal reproducible example in [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a902ee3a8cdf648d20aa32bc35ea35fe).

### TL;DR

Is it possible to borrow an object created at runtime (not necessarily created at the immediate start of the program) inside a `Mutex<Option<T>>` as mutable and for a `'static` lifetime?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you could get a mutable reference to a global static variable, you could do so multiple times, or in multiple threads, which is unsafe. For this reason, this isn't possible in safe code. You can [leak the contents of a `Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) to get a mutable static reference to a runtime-created object, though.